# Insert multiple row data in oracle 10g table using toad 10.5

Tags: oracle, toad

I am trying to insert multiple data in oracle using toad but not no error message shown nor no data insert into the said table.

```
    INSERT ALL
        INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('alahalia','alahalia')
        INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('alamudi','alamudi'),
        INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('albilad','albilad'),
        INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('aldar','aldar'),
        INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('alfalah','alfalah'),
        INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('almona','almona'),
        INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('ansari','ansari'),
        INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('ansari_eft','ansari_eft'),
        INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('bahfinance','bahfinance'),
        INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('bec','bec'),
        INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('bfc','bfc'),
        INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('city_int','city_int'),
        INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('city_spot','city_spot'),
        INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('dlc','dlc'),
        INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('gulf','gulf'),
        INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('habib','habib'),
        INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('ime','ime'),
        INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('imespot','imespot'),
        INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('kbi','kbi'),
        INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('modern','modern'),
        INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('mullah','mullah'),
        INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('muscat','muscat'),
        INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('muzaini','muzaini'),
        INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('nonoo','nonoo'),
        INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('oman','oman'),
        INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('oman_int','oman_int'),
        INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('oman_uae','oman_uae'),
        INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('prabhu','prabhu'),
        INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('prime','prime'),
        INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('rastamani','rastamani'),
        INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('tfr','tfr'),
        INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('tfr_spot','tfr_spot'),
        INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('uae','uae'),
        INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('uae_dubai','uae_dubai'),
        INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('uaekuwait','uaekuwait'),
        INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('wall','wall'),
        INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('western','western'),
        INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('xpressmoney','xpressmoney'),
        INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('zenj','zenj'),
        INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('zenj_spot','zenj_spot');

SELECT * FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the semicolon before `SELECT` and the commas after each `INTO` clause:

```
SQL> INSERT ALL
  2          INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('alahalia','alahalia')
  3          INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('alamudi','alamudi')
  4          INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('albilad','albilad')
  5          INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('aldar','aldar')
  6          INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('alfalah','alfalah')
  7          INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('almona','almona')
  8          INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('ansari','ansari')
  9          INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('ansari_eft','ansari_eft')
 10          INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('bahfinance','bahfinance')
 11          INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('bec','bec')
 12          INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('bfc','bfc')
 13          INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('city_int','city_int')
 14          INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('city_spot','city_spot')
 15          INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('dlc','dlc')
 16          INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('gulf','gulf')
 17          INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('habib','habib')
 18          INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('ime','ime')
 19          INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('imespot','imespot')
 20          INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('kbi','kbi')
 21          INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('modern','modern')
 22          INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('mullah','mullah')
 23          INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('muscat','muscat')
 24          INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('muzaini','muzaini')
 25          INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('nonoo','nonoo')
 26          INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('oman','oman')
 27          INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('oman_int','oman_int')
 28          INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('oman_uae','oman_uae')
 29          INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('prabhu','prabhu')
 30          INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('prime','prime')
 31          INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('rastamani','rastamani')
 32          INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('tfr','tfr')
 33          INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('tfr_spot','tfr_spot')
 34          INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('uae','uae')
 35          INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('uae_dubai','uae_dubai')
 36          INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('uaekuwait','uaekuwait')
 37          INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('wall','wall')
 38          INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('western','western')
 39          INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('xpressmoney','xpressmoney')
 40          INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('zenj','zenj')
 41          INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('zenj_spot','zenj_spot')
 42  SELECT * FROM DUAL;

40 rows created.

SQL>
SQL> select count(1)
  2  from nratuser;

  COUNT(1)
----------
        40

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am failed. I paste this code into toad editor  then execute . but the data not inserted in the table

Comment: Did you commit? I've just tried (edited my answer) and this works

Comment: Oh yeah I need to commit

Comment: is there any way drop multiple user using one statement using toad? `select 'drop user '||username||' cascade;' from dba_users
where username in ('NRAT','ALAHALIA')` I tried this

Comment: It's a completely different argument; better open a new question or try google for this

Answer (score 1):

You dont need `comma` at end of each line. Also remove `semicolon` at the end of last `insert`. Use this

```
INSERT ALL
    INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('alahalia','alahalia')
    INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('alamudi','alamudi')
    INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('albilad','albilad')
    INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('aldar','aldar')
    INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('alfalah','alfalah')
    INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('almona','almona')
    INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('ansari','ansari')
    INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('ansari_eft','ansari_eft')
    INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('bahfinance','bahfinance')
    INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('bec','bec')
    INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('bfc','bfc')
    INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('city_int','city_int')
    INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('city_spot','city_spot')
    INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('dlc','dlc')
    INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('gulf','gulf')
    INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('habib','habib')
    INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('ime','ime')
    INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('imespot','imespot')
    INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('kbi','kbi')
    INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('modern','modern')
    INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('mullah','mullah')
    INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('muscat','muscat')
    INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('muzaini','muzaini')
    INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('nonoo','nonoo')
    INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('oman','oman')
    INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('oman_int','oman_int')
    INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('oman_uae','oman_uae')
    INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('prabhu','prabhu')
    INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('prime','prime')
    INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('rastamani','rastamani')
    INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('tfr','tfr')
    INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('tfr_spot','tfr_spot')
    INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('uae','uae')
    INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('uae_dubai','uae_dubai')
    INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('uaekuwait','uaekuwait')
    INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('wall','wall')
    INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('western','western')
    INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('xpressmoney','xpressmoney')
    INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('zenj','zenj')
    INTO nratuser (username, password) VALUES ('zenj_spot','zenj_spot')

SELECT * FROM DUAL;
```